# Enumerating the elements of free distributive lattices

Tags: lattice-orders

Is there a simple/efficient way of enumerating the elements of a free distributive lattice?

(I'm doing some computations with them, and listing their elements in what's probably the least efficient way possible...)

Answer (score 1):

It's equivalent to enumerating monotone Boolean functions, e.g. see Fidytek et al. [Algorithms counting monotone Boolean functions](http://www.ii.uni.wroc.pl/~lorys/IPL/article79-6-4.pdf)

Comment: Notice I don't what their number but the actual list of formulas.